# Adding constrains in a SYM function "Classicalsymmetries"

Tags: functions, constraint

Please help me add constrains on my code. The function runs perfectly fine without the constrains but it gives me 7 cases and I only need one where all the constrains I have hold.

This is the code without constrains:
[image]

This is my code with constrains and it's not running.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code (not images) that can be copied, pasted and executed. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584).